# Magic Mouse Middle Click in Windows 7 64-bit Bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, mouse

This question might be similar to some that others have posted, but I want to be more specific: Does anyone know how to enable Magic Mouse's middle-click in Windows Bootcamp (specifically Win 7 x64)?

In OS X we can use [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/) or [Better Touch Tool](http://blog.boastr.net/), I'm looking for their counterparts in Windows. Also, this feature is enabled in Windows Guests if we use Parallels or VMWare Fusion while having the aforementioned tools active in OS X.

Comment: Shift + Option + Mouse Click doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think so..

Answer (score 1):

I have found a partial solution:

Using [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), an automation software for Windows, the middle-click can be simulated by pressing ctrl-left click using the following script:

```
#include <Misc.au3>

Global $iFlag = 0

While Not _IsPressed("1B") ;Esc to quit
    If _IsPressed("01") And _IsPressed("11") And Not $iFlag Then
        $iFlag = MouseDown("Middle")
    ElseIf Not _IsPressed("01") And Not _IsPressed("11") And $iFlag Then
        $iFlag = (MouseUp("Middle") <> 1)
    EndIf
    Sleep(20)
WEnd
```

The script is taken and modified from here: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/132174-simulate-middle-mouse-click/, which is exactly the same scenario that I am facing. The script can be compiled to an .exe, which I have already done. If anyone's interested, I can share it.

This solution has a drawback, however. It can only simulate middle-clicks, you can not middle-click-drags.